# Some webpages not loading in windows

Tags: windows-10, internet, website

I have windows 10 installed and I'm unable to open a few websites in windows which I'm able to open in virtual machines and live cds. I have tried it in both chrome and firefox. The blue circle in the browser's toolbar keeps on rotating. I have also tried disabling my anti-virus( eset smart security). How can I fix it?

[image: Chrome web tools screenshot]

Comment: does Edge work? or do you see the same issue?

Comment: same problem in edge

Comment: run network troubleshooter from Windows to make sure your Internet is working fine

Comment: I'm able to open all other pages except a few and I've tried network troubleshooter too

Comment: chrome and firefox have web dev tools, open them and trace page load. Maybe you see where the browsers hang

Comment: also use isup.me to check if the page is up or if it is down for DNS/Server issues

Comment: isup.me says that the websites are up

Comment: Added screenshot of chrome web dev tools

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so I put this in answer: it sounds like a `hosts` file problem, since you are able to browse these websites in a VM and it is a system-wide problem. (Which websites are these anyway?)

To access your host file and change its entries, you need to open notepad as an administrator and go to `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`. Then look for the websites you cannot access in the list.

It might otherwise be a firewall problem, in which case a temporary disable will help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Checked the hosts file, no entries related to the problematic websites(coursera, www.calculatorsoup.com, etc).